# Search on a given list on the client side

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, search

So I've got a list full of objects that I pass in my context to the client.

I want to make a text input which will `onchange()` search in the list the objects which `__unicode__` contains the value of the text input.

I want to put the objects which match my rule in a select as options.

I do not have any idea how to do that, I guess it involves some `jQuery` and that`s ok with me.

So please help me out here.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this might help you:

[jQuery filter a list using simple select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495603/jquery-filter-a-list-using-simple-select-box)

```
    $('#filtercountry').change(function(){
    var criteria = $(this).val();
    if(criteria == 'ALL'){
        $('.lilist').show();
        return;
    }
    $('.country').each(function(i,option){
        if($(this).html() == criteria){
            $(this).parent().show();
        }else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

In this example, the list is filtered by a drop down, but you can change it to a text input with onchange event.